# XMLHttpRequest возвращает не все данные

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Я пытаюсь отправить с сервера смешанные данные через ajax. В onreadystatechange ловлю так:

```
if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
{
    alert(this.responseText.length); //28457 байт
    func(this.responseText);        
}
```

С сервера отправляю с заголовком `application/x-binary`:

```
    print len(people[:])  #30037 байт
    response = HttpResponse(people, content_type='application/x-binary')
    return response
```

Пробовал так же `application/zip`, `image/jpeg` и `text/plain`. Проблема в том, что размер получаемых данных не совпадает с отправляемым: например, отправляю 30037, а приходит 28457. Проблема случается только при больших объемах данных. При обмене до 1000 байт потерь нет. При чем с каждым запросом теряется неизменяемое число байт.

При передачи обычного текста проблем не наблюдается. Только при передаче бинарных данных

Куда могут теряться данные и как это можно обойти?

Comment: Посмотрите, что там в 28458-м байте.

Comment: @Igor, символ с кодом 32. Я подумал, что,может, он отрезает - поставил его вначале текста, и никакого эффекта